# Create a dynamic table based on stored procedure in Crystal Reports 9

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a little problem I bumped into. I have a stored procedure that provides me with some quantities (e.g. 1,3,5). How can I translate this into a table? Do be more precise, for this kind of input, I select the max number, which is 5, and then I have to create an empty table with 3 columns and 5 rows like this:

1 1 1

0 1 1

0 1 1

0 0 1

0 0 1.

Can I do this in CR 9 ?